# I am new to ML, and trying to make a model to detect digits using webcam in openCV, Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I have trained an ML model using openCV, but when I am trying to open webcam and getting the model to work I am getting this error:

Code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import pickle
    import os
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

    width = 640
    height = 480

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    cap.set(3, width)
    cap.set(4, height)

    pickle_in = open("model_trained.p", "rb")
    model = pickle.load(pickle_in)


    def preProcessing(img):
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
        img = img / 255
        return img


    while True:
        success, imgOriginal = cap.read()
        img = np.asarray(imgOriginal)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (320, 320))
        img = preProcessing(img)
        cv2.imshow("Processed Img", img)

    if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Error:

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/basar/PycharmProjects/AdaniGas/main2.py", line 28, in <module>
    img = cv2.resize(img, (320, 320))
    TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Try `img = imgOriginal.copy()` instead of `img = np.asarray(imgOriginal)`

Comment: @Tiphel Given that `imgOriginal` is not used for anything else, even the copy is useless here. The `np.asarray` is puzzling, given that the output is already a numpy array (or None if the read fails) -- given that OP takes the popular approach of ignoring the success flag, it might have been a misguided attempt at stopping `resize` complaining about getting a NoneType.

Answer (score 0):

It started working, actually in the line
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
I put 0 instead of 1 because I am using webcam and it worked.